# Add new Headings to Profit and Loss - PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm struggling to get a P&L in the format I need.

In summary, my main table has these columns:

- Main Headings
- Month
- Total

They are working fine, but I want to display the "Main Headings" in a different way.
Ex.
The two headings "Net Fees" + "Other Income" will become "Total Income".
All the Main Overheads headings will become "Overheads" and so on ...

I though about adding an extra Table but I'm honestly not sure if this would be the best approach.
This is basically what I'm expecting to see (with the totals per month as the original view):

[image]

Would anyone be able to give some suggestions?

Comment: Could you update your question with what your "Main Headings" table looks.

Comment: That's just a column with headings, something like this:

Headings              Items              Category                       Total
Net Fees              Bad Debts        PL                                  500
Net Fees              Gross fees        PL                                  1500


I'm trying to summarise this table in a different format only for the dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a separate table with Category and Sub-Category would be one approach to this, together with using a Measure. You would then use this new table column as the Row for the Matrix visual.

Here's the approach:
**1: Create a new table, let's call it `Headings`**:

| Heading | Group |
| --- | --- |
| Net Fees | Total Income |
| Other Income | Total Income |
| ... | ... |

**2: Create a measure similar to this** (calling your main table `Main`):

```
HeadingTotal = 
  SWITCH(SELECTEDVALUE('Headings'),
    "Total Income", CALCULATE( SUM('Main'[Total]), 'Main'[Main Heading] IN VALUES('Headings'[Heading]) )
    "Overheads", CALCULATE(...)
  )
```

Give the above a go. Again, hopefully this is enough to give you and idea of an approach.

Comment: That's exactly what I have been trying to do. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: How did it go? Need any more on this?